# Adword Conversation Tracking: Non-standard implementation error

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I added Adword Conversation Tracking to my webshop.
I have Magento shop and inside of *body* tag I have following code:

```
<!-- Google Code for Conversion_Adwords_DrSchaette Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
    var google_conversion_language = "de";
    var google_conversion_format = "2";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "RstGBPX52wEEk8Dz4wS";
    var google_conversion_currency = "EUR";
    var google_conversion_value = 1.00;
    var google_remarketing_only = false;
    var google_conversion_order_id = "100031728";
/* ]]> */
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>

<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" 
            src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/123456789/?value=1.00&currency_code=EUR&label=RstGBPX52wEEk8Dz4wS&guid=ON&oid=100031728&script=0"/>
     </div>
</noscript>
```

**Google tag assistant** report me  following errors:

- Code should be placed directly above the closing  tag.
- Conversion Value should be prefixed with standard currency.
- Non-standard implementation

First error I know what it is, but second and third I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Unless you have implemented this via GTM in a custom HTML tag (which you say you have not) you might want to remove the [google-tag-manager] tag.

Answer (score 1):

If the conversions are appearing properly in your AdWords account, then you can safely ignore these warnings. Google Tag Assistant can be a bit buggy sometimes.